# Show ListView in Dialog of OnLongClick of a Button

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, customdialog

I'm using a Custom Dialog, which is called on Long Click of a button named pg.
I want to Show a ListView in the Custom Dialog,
**Both ListView and Custom Dialog have same xml file: custome_dialog**.
The Problem is: App crashes when I try to declare the Adapter of ListView.
Here is my Java Code of **Gorups.this** :

```
public class Gorups extends AppCompatActivity {


    Button pg;
    ListView pglist;
    private static String[] NAMES=new String[]{
            "A","B","C"
    }; //Items To show in ListView

    @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gorups);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);    


        //LongClick on PG////////////////////////////////////Start
        pg=findViewById(R.id.pgbtn);
        pg.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

                final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Gorups.this);
                view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custome_dialog,null);


                dialog.setView(view);
                AlertDialog customDialog = dialog.create();
                customDialog.setTitle("Saved Contacts");
                customDialog.setMessage("Dialog is Shown");

                //Declaring ListView Adapter
                    pglist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvpg);
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(Gorups.this, R.layout.custome_dialog, NAMES);
                    pglist.setAdapter(adapter);




                //Calling ListView:--//////////////////////////////////////////////////

                pglist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                        String value=(String)pglist.getItemAtPosition(position);
                        Toast.makeText(Gorups.this,"U pressed: "+position+" and: "+value,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                customDialog.show();

                return true;
            }
        });
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    }
```

Here is custome_dialog.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvpg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

What could be wrong with it?

Comment: 1) Post the code of R.layout.custome_dialog. You are setting the same layout for the dialog and the adapter item
2) if you want to access the listview inside the layout, you should change findViewById with view.findViewById

Comment: Done All.
No Success :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
pglist = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.lvpg);
```

instead of this

```
pglist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvpg);
```

> Another issue is you are setting  same layout to your `listview` adapter **custome_dialog** check it

try this

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(Gorups.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, NAMES);
```

> OR TRy this

```
Dialog dialog=new Dialog(Gorups.this);
dialog.setTitle("Saved Contacts");     
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custome_dialog);     
pglist = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.lvpg);;    


 ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        Gorups.this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, NAMES );
pglist.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
dialog.show();
```

**EDIT**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvpg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: did you get any crash log @ZubairYounas

Comment: Sorry,
I don't know how to use Log,
I tried it, But It does not show anything in Logcat.
I'm not using any emulator, I use my android phone.

Comment: @ZubairYounas why you are setting same layout **`R.layout.custome_dialog`** to Adapter

Comment: I tried using separate:
One for Custom Dialog and one for ListView
Still Doesn't work :(

Comment: Let me Try that Again with separate xml

Comment: Tried the updated answer: with same and Separate xml
No Sucess :(

Comment: @ZubairYounas updated ans means this **`ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(Gorups.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, NAMES);`**

Comment: Yes Dear
I tried this:
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(Gorups.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, NAMES);

No Sucess:(

Comment: @ZubairYounas share your layout of **R.layout.custome_dialog**

Comment: @ZubairYounas check updated ans my friend it will sure help you

Comment: Tried the updated answer.
Now it Shows the Dialog with title as Set.
But there is No ListView in Dialog.

Comment: Tried the updated answer.
Now it Shows the Dialog with title as Set.
But there is No ListView in Dialog.

Comment: @ZubairYounas share your **R.layout.custome_dialog** with question because it working fine in my device

Comment: Check the Updated Question Dear
I've posted **R.layout.custome_dialog**

Comment: @ZubairYounas set **android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"** to your Linear layout

Comment: In your device, 
Are you using same xml file for ListView and as well for Dialog?

Comment: @ZubairYounas happy to help you my friend

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this line:

```
view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custome_dialog,null);
```

Use:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custome_dialog,null);
```

also use:

```
pglist = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.lvpg);
```

instead of:

```
pglist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvpg);
```

**And replace all Groups.this with getContext()**

And replace this:

```
new ArrayAdapter<>(Gorups.this, R.layout.custome_dialog, NAMES);
```

with:

```
new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, NAMES);
```

Comment: Apply all explained changes then you will be fine to go :)

Comment: Done All.
No Success